# What should I #include to use 'htonl'?

Tags: c, include, endianness

I want to use the `htonl` function in my ruby c extension, but don't want to use any of the other internet stuff that comes with it. What would be the most minimalistic file to `#include` that is still portable? Looking through the header files on my computer, I can see that either `machine/endian.h` or `sys/_endian.h` would let me use them, although I am not sure if that is a good idea.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [standard](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/htonl.html) header is:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

You don't have to worry about the other stuff defined in that header.  It won't affect your compiled code, and should have only a minor effect on compilation time.

EDIT: You can test this.  Create two files, htonl_manual.c

```
// non-portable, minimalistic header
#include <byteswap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    x = __bswap_32(x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

and htonl_include.c:

```
// portable
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    x = htonl(x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Assemble them at -O1, then take the difference:

```
gcc htonl_manual.c -o htonl_manual.s -S -O1
gcc htonl_include.c -o htonl_include.s -S -O1
diff htonl_include.s htonl_manual.s
```

For me, the only difference is the filename.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that it wouldn't change the compiled code. Before you answered, I was considering writing my own version just so that my code could stay small.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, `arpa/inet.h` doesn't exist so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173653/6451573)  won't do. The include is:

```
#include <winsock.h>
```

So a portable version of the include block (always better to provide one):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <winsock.h>
#else
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
```

Comment: is there any portable single include available in c++? or do we also have to #ifdef

Comment: not going to happen apparently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638213/will-and-should-there-be-sockets-in-c11

Comment: right. Just letting you know I time traveled 2 years in the past and commented on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61319938/9906706) particular answer